# IntelliJ can't find depencency when compiling, but can in editor.

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, dependencies

In my Java IntelliJ project, I am able to load the source code and dependencies and I am able to even `Go To --> Declaration` like this:

[image]

However, when it comes time to compile, it cannot find the source code behind it!

[image]

And I am fairly sure I set up my dependencies properly:

[image]

So I am failing to understand why IntellJ is spitting out those errors. This project works just fine in Eclipse, but I am looking to start moving away from eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had added a folder for dependency (not a jar or module) with sources and compiled classes in it. This is perfectly legal and obviously IDEA managed to recognize the source folder but failed for the classes folder.

Press "Edit" on your selected dependency (the green pencil icon). The dialog that opens show "Classes" and "Sources" folders. Add the exact folder in which the classes and packages are (not the root project folder).

Comment: That solved this issue, now I have a new one. Code within the same project can't find each other's symbols. It may be worth a new question with its own screen shots since it is hard to show this.

Comment: Added a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778279/intellij-cant-find-classes-in-same-package-when-compiling